# Convergence of solution of PDE as forcing term varies.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-operators

Let $L$ be an elliptic operator.

We have the PDE

$Lf(x; y) = u(x; y)$

on some domain $\Omega$ with Dirichlet boundary condition.
Suppose we know that each PDE admits unique solution.

$u$ is a sequence of $C^1$ function, known to converge (at least pointwise), as y converges to infinity. What result do we have about convergence of $f(x; y)$?

Comment: Please add more context. As of now not much is known. e.g. take $u(x, y)  = 0$ and $L = \Delta$, then this is just a harmonic functions with no extra assumptions.

Comment: @ArcticChar that is a good point.